# Reduce multiple if conditions from the method to meet SonarQube requirments

Tags: java

```
private UriBuilder buildDateParams(UriBuilder builder, FilterDateParams filterDateParams) {
    if (filterDateParams != null) {
        if (filterDateParams.getDateCreated_gt() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("dateCreated_gt", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getDateCreated_gt() });
        }
        if (filterDateParams.getDateCreated_gte() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("dateCreated_gte", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getDateCreated_gte() });
        }
        if (filterDateParams.getDateCreated_lt() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("dateCreated_lt", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getDateCreated_lt() });
        }
        if (filterDateParams.getDateCreated_lte() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("dateCreated_lte", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getDateCreated_lte() });
        }
        if (filterDateParams.getLastUpdated_gt() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("lastUpdated_gt", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getLastUpdated_gt() });
        }
        if (filterDateParams.getLastUpdated_gte() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("lastUpdated_gte", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getLastUpdated_gte() });
        }
        if (filterDateParams.getLastUpdated_lt() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("lastUpdated_lt", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getLastUpdated_lt() });
        }
        if (filterDateParams.getLastUpdated_lte() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("lastUpdated_lte", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getLastUpdated_lte() });
        }
        if (filterDateParams.getStartDate_gt() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("startDate_gt", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getStartDate_gt() });
        }
        if (filterDateParams.getStartDate_gte() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("startDate_gte", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getStartDate_gte() });
        }
        if (filterDateParams.getStartDate_lt() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("startDate_lt", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getStartDate_lt() });
        }
        if (filterDateParams.getStartDate_lte() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("startDate_lte", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getStartDate_lte() });
        }
        if (filterDateParams.getEndDate_gt() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("endDate_gt", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getEndDate_gt() });
        }
        if (filterDateParams.getEndDate_gte() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("endDate_gte", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getEndDate_gte() });
        }
        if (filterDateParams.getEndDate_lt() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("endDate_lt", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getEndDate_lt() });
        }
        if (filterDateParams.getEndDate_lte() != null) {
            builder.queryParam("endDate_lte", new Object[] { filterDateParams.getEndDate_lte() });
        }
    }
    return builder;
}
```

Method gets larger & i need to reduce no of lines as sonarQube considering as smelly code.
I can't use ternary operator. Can someone give best prectices example for the same?
I tried too many things but all if conditions are necessary.

Comment: Not sure if this is an option, but this looks like a good scenario for Groovy and reflective properties. If you can use reflection, this can go in a simple loop or iterator.

Comment: I wouldn't go with reflection unless there is no other option, it's heavy, slow and you'll find errors only in runtime.

Comment: If possible you could make a Map<String,Date> of filterDateParams and iterate over the entries.

Comment: This looks like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - not for SO.

Comment: @mpf82 nope. Even though it seems that he asked for review, he pointed a specific issue with the current implementation and asked how to solve it. It would fit in codereview as well, but it's perfectly fine to post it here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a method of it:

```
buildParamater(builder,"dateCreated_gt",filterDateParams.getDateCreated_gt());
buildParamater(builder,"dateCreated_gte",filterDateParams.getDateCreated_gte());
...
```

You will have only one not-null-Check in the method. For example:

```
private void buildParamater(UriBuilder builder, String key, Date val) {
     if (null != val) {
            builder.queryParam(key, new Object[] { val });
     }
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you showed how you intend `buildParamater` to look like, nevertheless I can see how it collapses all the `if`s statements into one. This is indeed an improvement but still doesn't solve the rest of the boilerplate code

Comment: @alfasin what about the boilerplate in your answer? The `FilterDateParams` class requires you to pass all the parameters to `build` (and you have to do that everywhere you want to invoke `build`), and then put all the parameters into the map. Turo's solution is much simpler.

Comment: @AndyTurner this question was already answered: it's the part that starts with "Since we have to set ..." please read till the end.

Comment: @alfasin your answer doesn't really address my point. You have three times the boilerplate (you have to add a new value to the parameter list; to the call sites of the method; and to the code adding the value to the map). Turo's answer just has one of these (the equivalent of adding to the map; just there is no additional map).

Comment: @AndyTurner I consider it my failure to explain it *properly*. You have to set these parameters, either as fields or  as a map. Setting them as fields requires either a constructor or a setter that will do it. You can't avoid the "boilerplate" code of setting these fields. whether it's done via. fields or Map doesn't matter - you still have to do it at least *once*. That said, after you've done it, in the method I created you can easily iterate them as map-entries, while in Turo's case you'll have to explicitly call `buildParamater` for each one of them. I hope that now it's clearer.

Answer (score 2):

As some people suggested - it seems that class `FilterDateParams` requires re-architecture. Since you're looking at certain String keys and their values, it sounds like using a Map could be a good idea, this way you can iterate the entries, check for null condition and apply the requested logic respectively. The following is one way to do it:

```
class FilterDateParams {

    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    private FilterDateParams() {}

    public static FilterDateParams build(String dateCreated_gt,
                                          String dateCreated_gte,
                                          String dateCreated_lt,
                                          String dateCreated_lte) {
                                          // and etc...

        FilterDateParams fdp = new FilterDateParams();
        fdp.map.put("dateCreated_gt", dateCreated_gt);
        fdp.map.put("dateCreated_gte", dateCreated_gte);
        fdp.map.put("dateCreated_lt", dateCreated_lt);
        fdp.map.put("dateCreated_lt", dateCreated_lt);
        fdp.map.put("dateCreated_lte", dateCreated_lte);
        // and etc

        return fdp;
    }

    public void buildParams(UriBuilder builder) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (null != entry.getValue()) {
                builder.queryParam(entry.getKey(), new Object[] {entry.getValue()});
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

Note that a static factory is used to create instances of the class, when we want to create an instance we call it with the required parameters, for example:

```
FilterDateParams filterDateParams = FilterDateParams.build("a", "b", "c", "d");
```

and later on to build the query-params:

```
filterDateParams.buildParams(builder);
```

Since we have to set the parameters at least once, we cannot avoid the doing the following:

```
    fdp.map.put("dateCreated_gt", dateCreated_gt);
    fdp.map.put("dateCreated_gte", dateCreated_gte);
    ...
```

It's equivalent to using setters or constructor to set each one of these fields which means that there is actually *real* no repetition here!

Further, once all is set, you can use the map-entries to iterate over the keys/values without the need to do the same repetition again and again (such as in Turo's answer).

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't understand your reasoning. Having 16 parameters is error-prone ?  than calling these 16 parameters one-by-one again and again is even *more* so. The suggested solution here is doing it only once, what Turo suggested requires repeatedly calling each one of them explicitly again and again. So, which one of the approaches is more error prone ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually such code gives a hint on an architectural problem.

From my point of view it would be better to refactor the `FilterDateParams` class to possibly provide a method `getStartDate(Identifier identifier)`, `getEndDate(Identifier identifier)` and use an enum `Identifier` that you can iterate over.

But for that I would need more code to see what this class actually does.